# What are common values for uninitialized memory for debugging?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, memory, assembly

A long time ago I learned about filling unused / uninitialized memory with `0xDEADBEEF` so that in a debugger or a crash report if I ever see that value I know I'm looking at uninitialized memory. I saw from a crash report iOS uses `0xBBADBEEF`.

What other creative values have people used? Do any particular values have any kind of specific benefit?

The most obvious benefit of values that turn into words is that, at least of most people, if the words are in their language they stick out easily where as some strictly numeric value is less likely to stick out.

But, maybe there are other reason to pick numbers? For example an odd number might crash a processors (68000) for example on certain memory accesses so it's probably better to pick `0x0BADBEEF` over `0xBADBEEF0`. Are their any other values (maybe processor specific) that have a concrete benefit for using for uninitialized memory?

Comment: I'm sure some people that hate fun will want to close this question as opinion-based or something.  Honestly, a giant list / survey question isn't a great fit for SO, but this one does amuse me and I think we can afford to keep it around.

Comment: You assume that most people does something like that. I assume that most people *don't*, and instead relies on the debuggers defaults.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, you want a value which is unlikely to happen to "work" when interpreted as either an integer, a pointer, or a string. So, here are a few constraints:

- Don't use a value that's a multiple of the smallest "usual" alignment on your target architecture. For x86, that's 4 (bytes), so no values that are divisible by 4. This ensures that if the value is interpreted as a pointer, it'll be obviously-incorrect. If you're on a non-x86 architecture, you might even be able to use a value that will cause an alignment trap if used as a pointer.
- Don't use a value which could reasonably be a small (positive or negative) integer. Your typical "int" variable in a C program never gets larger than 1,000 or so, so don't use small numbers as your empty data fill.
- Don't use a value which is composed entirely of valid ASCII characters. Make sure there's at least one byte in there with the high bit set. These days, you'd want to make sure they weren't valid UTF-8 or possibly UTF-16 values, either.
- Don't have any zero bytes in the value. There are too many cases where this would work out to be "helpful" to keeping the program from crashing - terminating a string, giving a non-int field a reasonable-looking value, etc.
- Don't use a single (or two) byte values, repeated over and over. Having a full-word length pattern can make it easier to determine how your wild pointer ended up pointing where it is, at least narrowing down which operations offset it from the start of the pattern.
- Don't use a value that maps to an valid address for a "typical" process. If the highest bits are set, it'll typically take a whole lot of malloc() before your process will grow large enough to make that a valid address.

Perhaps unsurprisingly, patterns like `0xDEADBEEF` meet basically all of these requirements.

Comment: Nice, this is a more complete list of requirements for poison values than I came up with.  You should add: as a pointer, doesn't point into a part of virtual memory that usually gets mapped by most processes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added.

Answer (score 5):

One technical term for values like this is "poison value".

Hex numbers that form English words are called Hexspeak.  **[Wikipedia's Hexspeak article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak) pretty much answers this question**, cataloguing many known constants in use for various things, including several that are used as poison values / canaries / sanity checks, as well as other uses like error codes or IPv6 addresses.

---

I seem to recall some variation of `0xBADF00D`.  (maybe with a repeated letter like your 2nd example).

There's also `0xDEADC0DE`.  (Googling for where I've seen this used found the wikipedia article linked above).

---

Other English words in hex I've seen: Java `.class` files use `0xCAFEBABE` as the magic number (first 4 bytes of the file).  As a play on this, I guess, the Jikes JVM uses `0xDEADBABE` as a sanity check constant.

Apparently Java wasn't the first user of `0xCAFEBABE`.  Wikipedia says "[It was originally created by NeXTSTEP developers as a reference to the baristas at Peet's Coffee & Tea](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/whyCAFEBABE.html)", and was used by the people developing Java *before* they thought of the name "Java".  So it didn't come out of Java -> coffee (if anything the other way around), it's just plain old non-feminist tech culture. :(

---

re: update: **Choosing a good value**.  For a poison value (not an error code), you want all the bytes to be different and not `0x00` or `0xFF`, since those are probably the most likely values for an errant single-byte store.  This applies especially for things like stack canaries (to detect buffer overruns), or other cases where detecting that it didn't get overwritten is important.

Your speculation about picking an odd value makes a lot of sense.  **Not being a valid memory address in the virtual memory layout of typical processes is a big advantage**.  Failing noisily as early as possible is optimal for debugging.  Anyway, this probably means that having the high bit set is a good idea, so `0x0...` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I wonder if that's has any significance to the person that chose it as in maybe they had a crush on someone or maybe it was just a random word they were able to make.

Comment: @gman: It's Java; it's all about coffee.  IDK why they thought "babe" was a good English word to include in the language file format, though.  It's not the most feminist choice.